# How to create Liquibase changeset for below Postgres index creation statement - concat 2 columns in index

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

```
create index if not exists employee_index 
   on employee(emp_id, (emp_first_name|| ' ' ||emp_last_name));
```

I'm able to use the above statement in Postgres, I want to have it in my Liquibase changeset. I need to combine the first and last names as above in the index since it gives better performance. I was told that I can't deviate from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an expression based index by enclosing the expression in parentheses:

```xml
<createIndex tableName="employee" indexName="employee_index">
  <column name="emp_id"/>
  <column name="(emp_first_name||' '||emp_last_name)"/>
</createIndex>
```

Comment: <column name="(emp_first_name||' '||emp_last_name)"/>
</createIndex>.  This throws sytax error in Liquibase.

Comment: @VasudevanSivalingam [works for me](https://i.imgur.com/fCscoso.png)

Comment: Yes. You are correct. It's working. Sorry for my wrong info.

Comment: The build fails during integration testing since I use H2 in-memory DB for the integration test. H2 DB gives SQL syntax error for the above changeset. So I need to find a way to exclude the above changeset execution for H2 in-memory DB. Is there a way to exclude the above changeset for H2 in-memory DB?